# How to add a Scrollable text area to a custom Dialog box?

Tags: installshield, installscript

I'm using InstallShield Professional 2013, and I'm having troubles including a scrollable text area in a custom dialog box (like the SdLincenseE RTF dialog box).

I have tried using a normal Text area but it only displays the raw text.  Is there a way to add the scrollable text area so it will display the contents of an rtf file like the SdLicenseEx RTF?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work around this issue by copying and renaming the `SdLicenseEx` followed by writing a function to handle the scrollable text area.

If not sure if this is the best way to handle this in an installscript project, but it worked for me.